# How to create a timer for every time this int changes? Java

Tags: java, random, time, timer, int

I'm trying to create the behavior for an enemy in a 2d game I'm making for fun, practice, and learning purposes. The way I'm doing its movement is having it randomly change its coordinates by a random amount (-5 to 5) but it's doing it very fast.

Here's my code

```
public void EnemyMovement() 
    {
Random randomnum = new Random();
enemyX += randomnum.nextInt(5);
enemyX -= randomnum.nextInt(5);
enemyY += randomnum.nextInt(5);
enemyY -= randomnum.nextInt(5);
```

}

Comment: Use `javax.swing.Timer` for your 2d game.

Comment: If you want to make it slow you can use Thread.sleep(1000);

Comment: I'll look into that Masud.

Comment: Rajeev, that makes the entire game run at 1 FPS.

Comment: You can increase timing according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to create a new thread that runs in the background. This will then execute a given task at a specified interval

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import java.util.Random;

public class TimeMove {

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();;
    Random randomnum = new Random();

    public void moveNow() {
        int moveX = randomnum.nextInt(5);
        int moveY = randomnum.nextInt(5);
        System.out.println("Moving " + moveX + ", " + moveY);
    }

    public void startRandomMover()  {
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
                moveNow();
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeMove mover = new TimeMove();
        mover.startRandomMover();
    }
}
```

Note the code `0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS`. This means that the timer will start with a `0` second delay, and then be called every `1` second.